# Kill process by part of name

Tags: c#, .net, process

Can please some one tell me how to kill a process by part of name? Example: I want to kill "explorer" but in code I want to implant to kill it by word "explor" and the rest should find out by code. Here is the code so far:

```
    Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        foreach (Process p in localByName)
        {
            p.Kill();


        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get all of the processes, then search afterwards:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(var p in processes.Where(proc => proc.ProcessName.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
   p.Kill();
```

Comment: I just wana search by part of name directly

Comment: @xeLinxel That's what this will do - in a case insensitive manner (so your example would work)

Comment: @xeLinxel The `searchString` variable here is the "part of the name" you want to find.

Answer (score 5):

```
var localByName = Process.GetProcesses()
                         .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("explor"));
foreach (Process p in localByName)
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Note that you may want to do a case insensitive search here, since it's process names.

Comment: Is diference that is uper case or not?

Comment: @xeLinxel see Reed's answer.